# I cannot add a new member to any TFS 2018 security group on collection or project level

Tags: tfs

My domain account is a member of all collection level security groups except Project Collection Proxy Service Accounts and Project Collection Test Service Accounts in our TFS 2018 on premises. In the past, I used to add new members to any security group on a collection or project level. However, I did some TFS security settings changes some time ago. Now, when I try to add a new member, I get an error message similar to this one:

> Unable to add members to this group.
> Failed to resolve the specified groups to join.
> You do not have sufficient permissions to add members to the following groups: [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Build Administrators

Unfortunately, I don't remember which security changes I did. I read the answer on a similar question in this web site where the problem was resolved by adding account to a Readers security group on a project level. The problem is I cannot add any account to Readers group either.

Can anyone, please, help to recover permission of adding a new member to a security group?

Thank you

Comment: I couldn't determine the specific permissions. You could try to use the `TFSSecurity.exe` to add the users to the Groups or change permission. Please check these two tickets:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814466/cannot-manage-security-in-tfs-2018-on-a-team-project-with-project-collection-adm and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/465579/cannot-manage-security-in-tfs-2018-on-a-team-proje.html. You could use the API to check the permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround for my issue. The current TFS 2018 that we are using went through multiple upgrades in the past (TFS 2010 -> TFS2012 -> TFS 2017 -> TFS 2018). The project that I had problem with was created in one of the earliest TFS version, i.e. it was quite old. I assume that this was the reason why I couldn't add any new members to the project. I have to note, this project did not have any Readers group members. The workaround was I created a new project and branched source code from the old project to the new one. I can add new members to any security group there.